# run database with rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, controllers, rspec-rails

I am trying to test a controller with RSpec but am having a problem because a function in the controller requires a database.

the line of code in the controller looks something like:

```
@myallresources = Myrsources.all
```

where Myresources just inherits from ActiveRecord::Base

however, because there is no database, there is nothing to load and @myallresources is just an empty array, causing the test to fail. Is there a way to connect to a database while running the rspec?

I am very new to RSpec and rails so any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a database connection in your controller specs.

Check the section about database isolation on this page http://rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html

Basically you have to mock or stub your ActiveRecord models, as those should be tested separately in the models specs. Here's a simple example using mock_model:

```
before do
  mocks = (1..3).map { mock_model(MyResource) }
  MyResource.should_receive(:all).and_return(mocks)
end
```

Put this inside the same block where reside the `describe` definition testing for the actions that use `MyResource.all`.

You can find good explanation of mocks and stubs in following links:

- http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/docs/mocks/mock-model
- http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/docs/mocks/stub-model